# creating a web application using Node.js

Tags: node.js, hyperledger

I am able to run a web application (using node) to serve all the API request and create/execute transaction on the blockchain.

Currently i have 4 VP (within Vagran) , and an instance of Node.js running locally on my pc.

However, in production mode, in order to be able to serve a high number of request (4000+/sec), should i be running multiple instance of my node.js (on different domains) and have each direct it's request to a specific (NVP -> VP)?

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you are trying to ask here, and you seem to have picked a tag that is completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Why not try it and benchmark the results? We don't know how it'll handle your requests, or whether its better using different chunks to handle these requests. Your code really dictates how it handles request, and whether it does it efficiently.

Comment: @Claies sorry if i didn't pick the proper tag.

Comment: @Dandy thank you for your reply.

Comment: could you please explain what are you trying to achieve and how you are trying to implement `hyperledger` in your case ? because in order for the ledger to work, all the peers in a network must be in sync at all times

Comment: @SufiyanGhori , Maybe i haven't explained myself properly. What i am trying to do is to balance all the request over the VP . I don't want all the request to be directed to the same VP. So i was thinking that but i having multiple instance of the nodes, where each will be forwarding the http request to a specific VP. As per the Answer below, i might need a load balancer instead. What are your thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you don't need to run on multiple instance. node can handle 4000/sec.

but if you feel that the server works slow, you can add load balance to handle it

Comment: Thank you .
I was thinking of using multiple instance so in that case the request will be balanced between the VPs , instead of having all the request sent to only one VP.
I will look into the load balance.

Comment: if you use docker, it is easy to scale and do load balance by using docker sworm

Comment: So in this case, u are suggesting that our application will be directing all the request to the same VP ? @AlongkornChetasumon